# How to send JSON data as Body using Retrofit android

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am trying to post below JSON array on server.

```
{
    "order": [{
            "orderid": "39",
            "dishid": "54",
            "quantity": "4",
            "userid":"2"
        },{
            "orderid": "39",
            "dishid": "54",
            "quantity": "4",
            "userid":"2"
        }]

}
```

I am using this below :

```
private void updateOreder() {

    M.showLoadingDialog(GetDishies.this);
    UpdateAPI mCommentsAPI = APIService.createService(UpdateAPI.class);

    mCommentsAPI.updateorder(jsonObject, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            M.hideLoadingDialog();
            Log.e("ssss",s.toString());
            Log.e("ssss", response.getReason());
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            M.hideLoadingDialog();
            Log.e("error",error.toString());
        }

    });

}
```

I am getting below error:

```
 retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 6 path $
```

updateApi Code:

```
@POST("updateorder.php")
    void updateorder(@Body JSONObject object,Callback<String>());
```

Can any one please tell me my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to activate traces to see what goes over the line. Chances are, the problem is in the answer of the server.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the answer. There is nothing to trace here. It does not send data to server.

Comment: Please post also your UpdateAPI code.

Answer (score 6):

Create OrderRequest Class

```
public class OrderRequest {

@SerializedName("order")
public List<Order> orders;
}
```

create Order Class

```
    public class Order {

    @SerializedName("orderid")
    public String Id;
}
```

EndPoint

```
public interface ApiEndpoint{
  @POST("order")
  Call<String> createOrder(@Body OrderRequest order, @HeaderMap HashMap<String,String> headerMap);
}
```

Use this type of implementation in the mainActivity which call to service

```
HashMap hashMap= new HashMap();
    hashMap.put("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8");

OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest();
List<Orders> orderList = new ArrayList();

Orders order = new Order();
order.Id = "20";
orderList.add(order);
//you can add many objects

orderRequest.orders = orderList;

Call<String> dataResponse= apiEndPoint.createOrder(orderRequest,hashMap)
dataResponse.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            try{

            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
```

In the createOrder method we donot need to convert object into Json. Because when we build retrofit we add converter factory as a GsonConverterFactory. It will automatic convert that object to the JSON

```
 retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 5):

try to modify your code to Retrofit 2

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

Your service :

```
@POST("updateorder.php")
Call<String> updateorder(@Body JsonObject object);
```

Call retrofit

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(RetrofitService.baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Pass your Json using GSON :

```
JsonObject postParam = new JsonObject
postParam.addProperty("order",yourArray) ;
```

Finally :

```
Call<String> call = retrofitService.updateorder(postParam);


    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<String>callback,Response<String>response) {
            String res = response.body();
         }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
    });
```

I hope to be helpful for you .

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to post a JSON request using Retrofit then there are two methods to follow.

1. Option one - Seraialized Object
Create a serializable object(In simple terms convert your JSON object into a class) and post it using Retrofit.
If you don't know how to do it use this URL to
```

convert your JSon object to a class [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

```
Example : Lets say in your case JSon object class name is Order.
```

Then inside the class you have to define your variables that matches to JSon structure.(Inner block define by [] is an array of objects). And you have to define getters and setters(I didn't include them here to save spacing)

```
public class Order implements Serializable{
private List<Order> order = null; //Include getters and setters
}

2. Option Two - Raw json (I prefer this one)
Create a JsonObject object and pass it (Remember not a JSONObject. Though both appears to be the same there is a distinct difference between them. Use exact same characters)

JsonObject bodyParameters = new JsonObject();
JsonArray details= new JsonArray();
JsonObject orderData= new JsonObject();
orderData.addProperty("orderid", "39");//You can parameterize these values by passing them
orderData.addProperty("dishid", "54");
orderData.addProperty("quantity", "4");
orderData.addProperty("userid", "2");
details.add(orderData)
bodyParameters.add("order", details);

Create Retrofit instance
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();

Retrofit Service(You have to create a service class and define instance)
@POST("<Your end point>")
Call<ResponseObject> updateOrder(@Body JsonObject bodyParameters);

Request Call
Call<ResponseObject> call = postsService.updateOrder(bodyParameters);
//postsService is the instance name of your Retrofit Service class
```

Answer (score 0):

using Retrofit version 2

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

1. create POJO class that corresponds to JSON structure that you will send to the server:

   ```
    public class RequestBody {
         private List<InnerClass> order;

         public RequestBody(List<InnerClass> order) {
            this.order = order;
         }

         public class InnerClass{
              private int orderid, dishid, quantity, userid;

              public InnerClass(int orderid, int dishid, int quantity, int userid) {
                this.orderid = orderid;
                this.dishid = dishid;
                this.quantity = quantity;
                this.userid = userid;
            }
            public int getOrderId() { return orderid; }
            public int getDishId() { return dishid; }
            public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
            public int getUserId() { return userid; }
         }
    }
   ```

   2. Create a servicegenerator class to initialize your Retrofic object instance:

      ```
       public class ServiceGenerator {

        private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

         public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
         Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                                 .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
                                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(okHttpClient).build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
      }
      ```
2. create the api service interface which should contain "updateorder" method:

   ```
   public interface ApiService {
       @POST("updateorder.php")
       Call<your POJO class that corresponds to your server response data> updateorder(@Body RequestBody object);
   }
   ```

4.inside your activity or fragment where you would like to make the request fill your Json data and initialize ApiService:

```
ArrayList<RequestBody.InnerClass> list = new List<>();
list.add(new RequestBody.InnerClass(39, 54, 4, 2));
list.add(new RequestBody.InnerClass(39, 54, 4, 2));
RequestBody requestBody = new RequestBody(list);

     ApiService apiService =    ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiService.class);
   Call<your POJO class that corresponds to your server response data> call = apiService.updateorder(requestBody);
//use enqueue for asynchronous requests 
call.enqueue(new Callback<your POJO class that corresponds to your server response data>() {

   public void onResponse(Response<> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
         M.hideLoadingDialog();
        Log.e("ssss",s.toString());
        Log.e("ssss", response.getReason());
   }

   public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
           M.hideLoadingDialog();
           Log.e("error",t.toString());
        }
}
```