# Retrofit: Sending POST request with JSON Array

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have `JsonElement jsonElement` object which I receive as response from my another GET request. `jsonElement.toString();`
looks like JSON array:

`[{"Id":493,"Number":"380936831127","FriendNumber":"380682140976"},{"Id":494,"Number":"380936831127","FriendNumber":"380638254108"}]`

I need to send this string via another POST request using Retrofit. How can I send jsonElement or String object via POST request?
How should look declaration of my method?
For example:

```
 @POST("/api/geo/getLoc")
    public void getFriendsLocation(/* something */,  Callback<JsonElement> response);
```

Comment: are you using spring mvc? there is annotation @RequestBody to do that in spring mvc

Comment: @neustart47: were you able to find solution to this? I am facing same problem. Not sure how I should pass json array. Any pointers would help! Thanks!

Comment: check my answer to similar question as yours..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775756/how-to-send-json-data-as-body-using-retrofit-android/36293022#36293022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sending data over request body your implementation should be like this:

1. Define model according to fields (CaseSensitive "Name" -> String Name etc  )
2. set your api function also like that

   ```
   @POST("/api/geo/getLoc")
   public void getFriendsLocation(@Body YourClass classObject,   Callback<JsonElement> response);
   ```
3. Use directly your created class object on post request

   ```
   getFriendsLocation(yourClassObjectThatIncludesFields, new Callback .... )
   ```

---

If your sending data over params You can do this with Gson.

1. Lets say you have a class that have fields like id , number and FriendNumber.Define a function :

   ```
   public static Map<String, Object> getMapFromObject(Object o) {
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       Type stringObjectMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType();
       return gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(o), stringObjectMap);
   }
   ```
2. set your api function also like that

   ```
   @POST("/api/geo/getLoc")
   public void getFriendsLocation(@QueryMap Map<String, Object>,     Callback<JsonElement> response);
   ```
3. When you are sending post request create object from your fields call this function like below here

   ```
   getFriendsLocation(getMapFromObject(yourClassObjectThatIncludesFields), new Callback .... )
   ```

I didnt write whole code which includes class definition and Callback function because they are up to your customization. I assume that you need to send over body so try the first way.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. I created a model class, after create an object of model class and handed it to getMapFromObject function. As result of work of this function i receive correct Map<String, Object> object. It looked like: [0]:"FriendNumber" -> "380935275259" [1]: "Number" -> "380936831127" [2]: "Id" -> "516.0". I saw that in debug mode.
But as result of request i recieve: 500 Internal Server Error.
Server work for sure right, so the problem in my code.
What's can be wrong ?

Comment: Are you doing that string parsing by hand on serverside ? Are you expecting that fields at the body of request or as parameters ? If you can share example working post request using software like Postman or etc. I can help more.

Comment: I don't know how server side working,all time i communicate with it with JSON arrays. This this the example from Postman:
http://snag.gy/JYwTu.jpg

Comment: I have edited answer according to that given extra information. You should implement the first way.