# Sending ArrayList<Array> POST request with Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

[image: image description here]

I have question :

How I can post up the server to use retrofit post?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787171/retrofit-sending-post-request-with-json-array

Comment: Thanks! Dheerubhai Bansal!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722617/retrofit-post-using-firebase

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried so far?

Comment: i try! and it success..thank all very much ^^.