# How do I delete “nameValuePairs” in a JSON request using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to send raw data in POST request but nameValuePairs key get concated with my JSON.

Here is my request method:-

```
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @POST("mpapi/seller/sellerprofilepost")
    Call<ResponseBody>
    updateProfile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                  @Body JSONObject body);
```

I am sending this:-

```
{
    "firstname": "test1ff"
}
```

but at backend they are receiving :-

```
{
    "nameValuePairs":
    {
        "firstname":"test1ff"

    }
}
```

Method for calling api :-

```
private void updateProfile() {
        try {
            showLoader();
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
            obj.put("firstname",first_name.getText().toString().trim());
            call = api.updateProfile("Bearer k8yu1q0k790lw5y4ta49alfbtsxoxs1w",obj);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    try {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                            dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, obj.getString("message"), ProfileScreen.this);
                        } else {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                            dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, obj.getString("message"), ProfileScreen.this);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), ProfileScreen.this);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    hideLoader();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), ProfileScreen.this);
                    hideLoader();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), this);
            hideLoader();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Retrofit call method :- here is my retrofit call method where I am setting base url, headers etc

```
public Retrofit retrofitCall() {
        String baseUrl = Constants.baseURL;
        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory())
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .addInterceptor(new AddHeaderInterceptor())
                .readTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Comment: plz add some code

Comment: add code from where you call updateProfile() method.

Comment: Instead of using JSONObject of android, Use JsonObject of GSON and construct the object with the method addProperty(String property, Value)

Comment: instead of `obj.put` try `obj.addProperty`

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36312617/8475893

Comment: I am using JSONObject not JsonObject

Comment: i tried the code ,it also happened to me no idea why howeveru can  use a hashmap in body or add your own custom class

Comment: Have already tried.

Comment: @Kartika u tried hashmap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your request method code as follow:

```
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
    @POST("mpapi/seller/sellerprofilepost")
    Call<ResponseBody>
    updateProfile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                  @Body RequestBody body);
```

In API Calling Method:

```
    private void updateProfile() {
            try {
                showLoader();
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                obj.put("firstname",first_name.getText().toString().trim());
                RequestBody bodyRequest = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), obj.toString());
                call = api.updateProfile("Bearer k8yu1q0k790lw5y4ta49alfbtsxoxs1w",bodyRequest);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        try {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                                dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, obj.getString("message"), ProfileScreen.this);
                            } else {
                                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                                dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, obj.getString("message"), ProfileScreen.this);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), ProfileScreen.this);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        hideLoader();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), ProfileScreen.this);
                        hideLoader();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), this);
                hideLoader();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**Or you can [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26065492/9293029) for alternate ways.**

Comment: Yes, I am using the same code and it is working fine for me. Have you notice that I am using RequestBody in Request method as well as in API call.

Comment: You can also refer to this answer. It is the same problem as yours. It uses the Model class and passes that Model class in the request method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26065492/9293029

Comment: Ya I am trying this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Viraj Patel, I have implemented code in below way and it is working fine :)

My request method code as follow:

```
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
@PUT("users/me/password-shares/")
fun sharePassword(@Body jsonObject: RequestBody): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Calling method will be

```
val request = jsonObject.toString().toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull());

var response = passwordService.sharePassword(request).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `retrofit` request as below,

```
retrofitResponse = new RetrofitResponse();
CommonPojo obj;

private void updateProfile() {
        try {
            showLoader();
            retrofitResponse.setFirst_name(first_name.getText().toString().trim());
            obj = new CommonPojo();
            obj.setJSONobj(retrofitResponse);

            call = api.updateProfile("Bearer k8yu1q0k790lw5y4ta49alfbtsxoxs1w",obj);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    try {
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                            dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, obj.getString("message"), ProfileScreen.this);
                        } else {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());
                            dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, obj.getString("message"), ProfileScreen.this);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), ProfileScreen.this);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    hideLoader();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), ProfileScreen.this);
                    hideLoader();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            dialog = Func.OneButtonDialog(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_MSG), this);
            hideLoader();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

RetrofitResponse.java

```
public class RetrofitResponse {

String first_name;

public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

}
```

Send post data with `Json` format, CommonPojo.java

```
public class CommonPojo {

 private RetrofitResponse JSONobj;

 public RetrofitResponse getJSONobj() {
        return JSONobj;
    }

    public void setJSONobj(RetrofitResponse JSONobj) {
        this.JSONobj = JSONobj;
    }

}
```

Try this and let me know if any help needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Map instead of JSONObject as follow:

```
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8")
@POST("mpapi/seller/sellerprofilepost")
Call<ResponseBody>
updateProfile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
              @Body Map<Object,Object> body);
```